# Is there some way of getting sysname in libusb like edev?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, libusb, udev

I need to get the device name of a device, which, by default, is on edev function:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/libudev-udev-device.html#udev-device-get-sysname

```
udev_device_get_sysname ()

const char *        udev_device_get_sysname             (struct             udev_device *udev_device);
udev_device :

udev device
Returns :

the sys name of the device device
```

But all the work with the device are done in libusb, it would be terrible to use udev only for the sysname, and it's really strange that I cannot find similar functions in libusb.

Anybody know about it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solve it on my own, in a very stupid way.

I got the busnum and devnum of a device in libusb, and iter all devices in udev, if a device has the same busnum and devnum, return it's sysname.

I get busnum by udev api, devnum by cat /syspath/devnum.

Vid Pid won't work since same devices have same ids.

Hope this will be of help.